# MFA One-time password image

Tags: auth0, one-time-password, multi-factor-authentication, totp

I'm using auth0 one-time password option to set up MFA in my application:
https://auth0.com/docs/mfa/guides/configure-otp

This allow users to set up the MFA with google authenticator or similar applications that read the QR code.

I'm also an user of this kind of MFA in multiple services, as for example, Slak, GitHub or Auth0 itself. I've seen that when having a lot of applications it can be a bit messy, but Slak or Github have their picture set up in the authenticator application.

Is there anyway I can setup the icon of my application using this option on Auth0? I guess the image is also in the QR code that is scanned. If auth0 doesn't give you that option, but it exists, is there any other option to generate the MFA QR for my users including my app icon?

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41232168/token-image-in-google-authenticator-or-freeotp

Answer (score 1):

I've seen in their code that https://freeotp.github.io/ uses a parameter image when generating the otpauth uri, even they refer to https://github.com/google/google-authenticator/wiki/Key-Uri-Format where there is no documentation about this parameter. It seems to work. The open standars [HOTP](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4226.txt) and [TOTP](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc6238.txt) neither has any information about the image, so I guess is not part of the standar.

No idea yet about how could I implement it with auth0, so bounty still open for that.